# how to invoke Clearbox3 gallery of photos from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, anchor, lightbox2

I have a webpage that has a list of anchors on it which use clearbox3 to display them as a gallery. Only the first anchor has a textual link to click "View Photos (3)". The others are just to get the images into the clearbox gallery. And that works fine. What I need is a way to bring up the clearbox image gallery from the user click of another control. I'm currenting trying to do it from an asp.net ImageButton control (maps to input tag), but have also tried to just use an anchor too without luck.

The anchors for the clearbox image gallery look like this:

```
<a id="photoLink" href="http://tempo5.sandicor.com/SNDImages/221/071064797_101_12.jpg" rel="clearbox[gallery=929 Border Ave, Del Mar, California, 92014,,tnhrf=http://tempo5.sandicor.com/SNDImages/221/071064797_101_12.jpg]">View Photos (6)</a>
<a href="http://tempo5.sandicor.com/SNDImages/221/071064797_201_22.jpg" rel="clearbox[gallery=929 Border Ave, Del Mar, California, 92014,,tnhrf=http://tempo5.sandicor.com/SNDImages/221/071064797_201_22.jpg]"></a>
<a href="http://tempo5.sandicor.com/SNDImages/221/071064797_301_22.jpg" rel="clearbox[gallery=929 Border Ave, Del Mar, California, 92014,,tnhrf=http://tempo5.sandicor.com/SNDImages/221/071064797_301_22.jpg]"></a>
```

My "other" control (currently an asp.net ImageButton --> maps to a an input control looks like this:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderCol2$mainPropertyPhoto" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCol2_mainPropertyPhoto" src="http://tempo5.sandicor.com/SNDImages/221/071064797_101_12.jpg" />
```

And finally, here the javascript I tried invoking from onClick attribute in ImageButton/Input control that didn't work with clearbox (and is not cross browser supported anyway):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickPhotoLink()
    {
        document.getElementById("photoLink").click();
    }
</script>
```

My question is this: how do I bring up the clearbox gallery I setup using the list of anchors above from another control such as an input control? I already tried using the onClick attribute (same as onClientClick property for asp.net) on the input to run a script, but had no luck there either invoking a .click() on the the first anchor in the list, nor was I able to rebuild another gallery exactly the same using the "CB_Open('href=mycontent,,parameter2=value 2,,parameter3=value 3,, ... ');" syntax defined on the clearbox page. The .click() won't work since it a) its not consistent across browsers, but b) more so because it's not actually the same as the user clicking the link. Also, using the CB_Open script to rebuild a duplicate gallery didn't seem like a very ideal option (nor could I get it to work) and the .click() just doesn't work with clearbox likely since its not actually the same as a user click.

So, I could change the ImageButton (input control) to be an anchor instead and set the href to the first in the gallery I'm displaying; and then set the other list of anchors to start with image #2 in the list. However, when the user clicks the textual link "View Photos (3)" it will bring up clearbox on the index of the 2nd photo and not the first. So that works, but isn't an ideal solution either since I need it to come up and show the 1st photo (from both places) which wouldn't make sense for clearbox since the href of the anchor points to image 2 and not 1.

Basically, I am wondering if there is a way to bring up my already defined/created clearbox gallery associted with the list of defined anchors on page from another control (possibly even another anchor, but without images from gallery to avoid duplication and/or issue outlined above)?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stackoverflow answer:

Solved. Instead of using an input control to initiate the click from, I switched it to an anchor control (with an image inside) and set the href attribute to execute the script directly instead of messing with the "onclick" and "rel" (used by clearbox) attributes to bring up the clearbox image gallery.

The resulting html is this:

```
<a href="javascript:CB_Open('gallery=929 Border Ave, Del Mar, California,  92014,,href=http://tempo5.sandicor.com/SNDImages/221/071064797_101_12.jpg');" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCol2_mainPhotoAnchor" class="mainPhotoAnchor"><img src="http://tempo5.sandicor.com/SNDImages/221/071064797_101_12.jpg" class="mainPhotoImage" /></a>
```

My asp.net code behind is this:

```
HtmlAnchor mainPhotoAnchor = new HtmlAnchor();
mainPhotoAnchor.InnerHtml = "<img src=\"" + arrPhotoUrls[0] + "\" class=\"mainPhotoImage\" />";
mainPhotoAnchor.HRef = "javascript:CB_Open('gallery=" + displayAddress + ",,href=" + arrPhotoUrls[0] + "');";
```